# Crystal reports - How to translate a group by with condition into a report

Tags: sql, ms-access, crystal-reports

I have the following query

```
SELECT dbo_DIRIGEANTS.IU_DIR, 
  [1-CR-liste_Pixi].Siren, 
  [1-CR-liste_Pixi].Nic,
FROM [1-CR-liste_Pixi] LEFT JOIN dbo_DIRIGEANTS ON [1-CR-liste_Pixi].Siren = dbo_DIRIGEANTS.SIREN
GROUP BY 
  dbo_DIRIGEANTS.IU_DIR, 
  [1-CR-liste_Pixi].Siren, 
  [1-CR-liste_Pixi].Nic, 
  IIf([QUAL_JUR]>"0003","",Right([QUAL_JUR],1))
HAVING 
  ((([1-CR-liste_Pixi].Siren) Not Like "p*") 
  AND (([1-CR-liste_Pixi].Nic) Not Like "p*") 
  AND ((dbo_DIRIGEANTS.REP_LEGAL)="1") AND (([1-CR-liste_Pixi].Nicsiège) Not Like "p*"))
ORDER BY IIf([QUAL_JUR]>"0003","",Right([QUAL_JUR],1));
```

What I'm interested is setting that part

> GROUP BY dbo_DIRIGEANTS.IU_DIR,
>
> [1-CR-liste_Pixi].Siren,
>
> [1-CR-liste_Pixi].Nic,
>
> IIf([QUAL_JUR]>"0003","",Right([QUAL_JUR],1))

And especially that part

> `IIf([QUAL_JUR]>"0003","",Right([QUAL_JUR],1))`

Because of performance, I kept my tables and use CR's functions to deal with the condition part instead of creating a query.

I did the following:

- Went to `Formula selection` and choose `group`

[image]

- Chose the field I wanted

[image]

- Put the formula

[image]

- The error below popped out

[image]

It said my formula needs to be using boolean values.

To see if I was right, I've amended it that way `IF {DIRIGEANTS.QUAL_JUR} > "0003" THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE`. It worked.

**TL;DR**

Why I cannot do that in my expert group selection?

> `IF {DIRIGEANTS.QUAL_JUR} > "0003" THEN "" ELSE RIGHT({QUAL_JUR},1)`

Thanks

Comment: Where did you write the formula....can you translate to English unable to understand

Comment: Hi @Siva formula is that `IF {DIRIGEANTS.QUAL_JUR} > "0003" THEN "" ELSE RIGHT({QUAL_JUR},1)`

Comment: That's fine where did you write the formula in which section

Comment: Your work is not that simple. For why your formula need to return boolean, read page 178. For a solution, find in page 17x of [RTM for CR](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-21510)

Comment: @Siva I wrote that in the `expert selection - group`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group selection should return Boolean but that doesn't mean you write true or false....it means you pass some thing to fields to perform job

```
IF {DIRIGEANTS.QUAL_JUR} > "0003"
 THEN datasefield=""
 ELSE database fled=RIGHT({QUAL_JUR},1)
```

This will do the job

Edit: Apologize as conditions are a bit confused for your requirement

Create formula and write below code

```
IF {DIRIGEANTS.QUAL_JUR} > "0003" THEN "" 
ELSE RIGHT({DIRIGEANTS.QUAL_JUR},1)
```

Now go to insert group and select this formula and click ok. This will do the trick

Comment: you mean like that `IF {DIRIGEANTS.QUAL_JUR} > "0003"
 THEN {DIRIGEANTS.QUAL_JUR}=""
 ELSE {DIRIGEANTS.QUAL_JUR}=RIGHT({DIRIGEANTS.QUAL_JUR},1)`? I did with your answer litteraly and I had an error `missing boolean argument`

Comment: Actually as per my idea and your query this should go to record selection not group selection

Comment: as said, I want to emulate a sql  `group by`. Will do the record selection do the trick?

Comment: @AndyK is the solution helpful to you? are you able to solve the problem?

Comment: Hi @Siva, I was going to work on the reports but another issue popped out. I'll give you a feedback later this afternoon. Many thanks for your help. The point are almost yours

Comment: Hi @Siva, it works. Many thanks for your help. You are great